# Using Pipes with a string array

Tags: c++, pipe, fork

Trying to create a pipe that can cout a string of random numbers. Splitting into parent and child, generating random numbers, writing to the pipe if child, reading if parent. I feel like this is close but my output is nonsense. Can someone please explain what a pipe does and point me in the correct direction as how to perform this action.

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>           /* c++ I/O headers */
#include <string.h>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

//Get the number of random numbers
int numberOfRandomNumbers = stoi(argv[1]);

//char childPipe[200], parentPipe[200]; //pipes to hold numbers
int pid, index, count; //counters
int pipe1[2]; // main pipe

int xyz = pipe(pipe1);  //perform the pipe 
string stringOfRandomNumbers = "";

pid = fork();   //fork the process

//check for errors-------------------------------------------
if(xyz < 0 || pid < 0){
    //break 
    cout << "Error" << endl;
    return 0;
} 

//Check process----------------------------------------------

if (pid == 0) {   /* child */

    srand(pid+4); //seed the random
    int randNum;


    //Start building the string
    stringOfRandomNumbers = "Child, ID = ";
    stringOfRandomNumbers += to_string(pid);
    stringOfRandomNumbers += ", Random numbers: >";


    //Now generate random numbers
    for (index = 0; index < numberOfRandomNumbers; index++) {

        randNum = rand() % 100;

        //add to string.....
        if(index == (numberOfRandomNumbers - 1)){
            //last one
            stringOfRandomNumbers += (to_string(randNum) + "<");
        }
        else{    

             stringOfRandomNumbers = stringOfRandomNumbers + (to_string(randNum) + ", ");  

        }

    }

    cout << endl << stringOfRandomNumbers << "  length = " << stringOfRandomNumbers.length() << endl;

    close(pipe1[0]);    //don't read off of pipe
    write(pipe1[1], stringOfRandomNumbers, stringOfRandomNumbers.length());
    close(pipe1[1]);    //done

}

else {      /* parent */


    // Now generate random numbers
    srand(pid+8);
    int randNum; 

    //Start the string
    stringOfRandomNumbers = "Parent, ID = ";
    stringOfRandomNumbers += to_string(pid);
    stringOfRandomNumbers += ", Random numbers: >";


    //Now generate random numbers
    for (index = 0; index < numberOfRandomNumbers; index++) {

        randNum = rand() % 100;

        //Add to string.....
        if(index == (numberOfRandomNumbers - 1)){
            //last one
            stringOfRandomNumbers += (to_string(randNum) + "<");
        }
        else{    

             stringOfRandomNumbers = stringOfRandomNumbers + (to_string(randNum) + ", ");  
        }
    } 

    close (pipe1[1]);   

    count = read(pipe1[0], stringOfRandomNumbers, stringOfRandomNumbers.length());

    for (index=0; index < count; index++){
            cout << stringOfRandomNumbers[index] << endl;
    }
    close (pipe1[0]);    //done 
}
}
```

Comment: Also any extra material on this subject would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you generating random numbers in the parent?  When you do a read call in the parent, you should provide a buffer and the maximum length to be read into the buffer.

Comment: Look at the documentation on the read call.  I don't believe it allows a `std::string` to be passed as an argument.

Comment: @DavidChoweller it sort of does. OP should be receiving at least a warning because it's not a pointer, but if it was a pointer, the `void *` parameter will eat anything without a complaint.

Comment: When debugging problems like this, it is often helpful to replace the call to `rand` with a function like `int dummy() { static int val=0; return val++; }` that doesn't produce random numbers - but random variations between runs make debugging hard.

Answer (score 2):

`read` and `write` are old school C functions. They have no clue what a C++ string is, and they fall back on assuming `stringOfRandomNumbers` is a pointer to the data you want to send or a buffer into which you wish to receive.

`stringOfRandomNumbers` is not a pointer, you should be getting a warning message, if not an outright refusal to compile, from the compiler about that. Even if it was a pointer, a `std::string` doesn't necessarily directly contain the data it represents. More often than not, a `std::string` points to a block of dynamically allocated storage, and if you `write` the `std::string`, you write the pointer rather than the data pointed to.

The receiving `std::string` now has a pointer to memory that makes sense in the sending process, but is meaningless or dangerous in the receiving process. If both are in the same process, then the memory is still valid, but you have two `std::string`s pointing to the same memory. As soon as one of the `std::string`s goes out of scope it will delete the memory and leave the other `std::string` pointing at invalid memory.

A really bad scene either way.

Next, because you would be sending the `std::string` object, and not the string data it would be dumb luck if the length of the string data exactly matched the `sizeof(std::string)` so either garbage data or not enough data will be sent.

What you want to do is something along the lines of

```
write(pipe1[1], stringOfRandomNumbers.c_str(), stringOfRandomNumbers.length()+1);
```

`std::string::c_str` gets a pointer to the buffer that contains the string data, and the +1 sends the buffer's terminating null so that the receiver knows where the string stops.

This approach leave you with a problem: How much data do I need to read? You have to keep reading from the pipe and append what's read to a `std::string` until the null is found. Kind of icky.

But

```
uint32_t len = stringOfRandomNumbers.length();
write(pipe1[1], &len, sizeof(len));
write(pipe1[1], stringOfRandomNumbers.c_str(), len);
```

Writes the length of the string first as a 32 bit unsigned integer and then writes `len` bytes from `stringOfRandomNumbers` buffer.

Caveat: `uint32_t`  is optional and may not be supported by your compiler. The idea is to make sure that both PCs know exactly how big the length is, so you may have to find a fixed size that both sender and receiver agree on.

On the receiving side,

```
uint32_t len;
read(pipe1[0], &len, sizeof(len)); //read len
std::vector<char> buffer(len+1); // Make buffer big enough for string and terminating null
read(pipe1[0], buffer.data(), len); // read into buffer
buffer[len] = '\0'; // null terminate
stringOfRandomNumbers = buffer.data();
```

The C++17 standard is projected to make this a bit easier because you will be able to request a non-`const` data pointer from a `std::string`. Size the `std::string` ahead of time and you can safely read directly into it.

Comment: In the context of a pipe, both processes are on the same machine (one is a forked copy of the other for heavens sake!) so an implementation-defined type like `int` would be fine.  In the context of a network, you probably want to be using htonl/ntohl.

Comment: In practise, you can size the read string, and then pass `&stringOfRandomNumbers[0]`.today.  In fact, I *think* that is guaranteed to work today.

Comment: Holy freaking stupid cut and paste mistake! Thanks, Martin.

Comment: It's one of those almost certain it'll work tricks, but I couldn't find anything in the standard that read like a guarantee so I left it out.